# Converting xp_cmdshell process to SSIS (2008R2) with delimited file output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Trying to convert an old xp_cmdshell process that creates output files from within a cursor.  I broke it down into a function call to pull a list of dates and a stored procedure that processes an individual day's worth of data.

When I try to get this working in SSIS, I keep going around in circles.  I have an OLE DB Source dataflow task that references the function stored in a variable.  I can pass that output to an OLE DB command that runs a sqlcommand "exec ?=export_data ?".

It's at this point where I get stuck.  I need to export each date as a separate file, but can't get the flat file destination to work.  I tried editing the function call with a second (null) column "result" to contain the output from each command call, but all I get is the '0' returnvalue instead of the in-memory table. I was able to get the recordset destination to work, but couldn't progress from there.

I know there's some extra work to be done with the flat file destination to get the distinct files, but I'd be happy just to get one file with some relevant data at this point.

Comment: I'm guessing you want Execute SQL Task with full result set to get the list of all the dates you need to process. Then a Foreach Loop to "shred the recordset" Within that, you have your data flow (although your syntax won't work b/c you can't dynamically substitute the stored procedure name. You can do it, but not in this manner. Your flat file connection manager needs to have an expression on the file name to change it out per loop in our foreach loop. All of this of course is dependent upon the structure of these exports being the same. Dynamic schema and a dataflow task don't go together.

Comment: The above comment is filled with phrases to run through your favorite search engine (or just look through my SSIS answers). If proc1 generates 3 columns, proc2 generates 5 columns, then you're out of luck and a duplicate of earlier questions asking how do we do dynamic data flows

Comment: The exports will all have the same structure.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: And never forget:  you can do pretty much anything with a script task.